# java WS client-server communication with certificates, what frameworks/apis should i use?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, client-server, ws-security

I have simple client-server communication thru WebServices.
Now, I'm using javax.ws.* and Endpoint class (is it a default implementation?) to create server side and Netbeans to create client side.

I have a basic knowledge about certificates etc.
I want clients to use (private?) certificate to sign (encrypt?) messages, so server knows (can identify) which particular client is calling.

So i have to generate private certificates for clients and public certificate for server?
Which APIs/frameworks (buzzwords like JAAS, ws-security, xwss, tls) should i use ?
Maybe just TLS could be enough for that ?

javax.ws.* - is it a reference implementation from Sun ?

I used SAAJ 1.3.4 and it works.
Now i have a question, how can i identify client (clients have unique private keys) can i extract some private key hash from SOAP envelope (to identify client) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Bouncycastle library, it's ligth weight and quite complete.

http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Comment: I used SAAJ 1.3.4 and it works.
Now i have a question, how can i identify client (clients have unique private keys) can i extract some private key hash from SOAP envelope (to identify client) ?

Comment: Usualy to identify a client the client should firm with his private key some text (a hash, or a chalenge text) and you can verify this signature using his public key. check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signing to get a better idea.

Comment: ok, i understand that, but the question is, while using XWSS, is there any hash in SOAP Header that i can use ? 
or maybe there is some XWSS feature for that?
 or should i place my own header attribute with some hash signed by client private key ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the client asks the server to identify itself and not the other way around. There is an option for a 2 way identification, I'm guessing you need to configure it.

I'd suggest using Axis2 for generating the client/service stub and Rampart for handling the security.

Rampart is an axis2 module that handles most of the security hustle for you.